# Check if App is running

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm developing an app that receives a push notification from the server and if the app is closed i wanted to show a local notification.

To do that i needed to check if the application is running in the foreground or in the background.

I tried finding this but i could not find something similar. I wanted to know if there is any way to check this in the core application or if i would need to create an interface and its implementations.

For example:

```
public interface IAppInfo 
{ 
    bool IsInForeground(); 
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is very platform specific and you need to use the API on the platform to detect that.

Comment: I imagined it would have to be like this just wasn't sure. Thanks =)